# SQL Server 2000 not able to use TVF in query

Tags: sql-server

I'm using SQL Server 2000, I've created a TVF as outlined below:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_GetName]
    (@ID NVARCHAR(MAX))
RETURNS TABLE
AS
    RETURN 
        SELECT Name
        FROM 
            (SELECT FirstName + ' ' + LastName Name
             FROM UserProfile
             WHERE 1 = 1
               AND UserID = @ID

             UNION 

             SELECT FirstName + ' ' + MiddleName + ' ' + LastName Name
             FROM Student
             WHERE 1 = 1
               AND StudentID = @ID
               AND Deleted IS NULL) query;
```

I'm trying to use it in this query:

```
SELECT un.Name AS UserName
FROM UserProfile up (NOLOCK)
CROSS APPLY (SELECT Name FROM dbo.fn_GetName(up.UserID)) un
```

I'm getting this error when I run the query:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 19
>   Incorrect syntax near '.'.

Just in case it matters the input value to the TVF is a GUID. Can someone please let me know what I'm doing wrong and how I can change my query so I can use the TVF that I created? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're running on an **ancient** version of SQL Server and trying to use `CROSS APPLY`? I don't know where to start. And since the `(max)` variants of data types didn't appear until 2005, I suspect serious misidentification *somewhere* here.

Comment: I believe you need to add `;` after `CROSS APPLY (SELECT Name FROM dbo.fn_GetName(up.UserID)) un` like `CROSS APPLY (SELECT Name FROM dbo.fn_GetName(up.UserID)) un;`

Comment: This question is a great example of why I've forced myself to use AS with aliases on columns

Comment: I know ms sql server 2000 is old, but I have to make do with what they give me at my job. I tried `CROSS APPLY (SELECT Name FROM dbo.fn_GetName(up.UserID)) un;` and `CROSS APPLY (SELECT Name FROM dbo.fn_GetName(up.UserID)); un` and `CROSS APPLY (SELECT Name FROM dbo.fn_GetName(up.UserID);) un` and they all still give me the error in my OP

Comment: @I_am_Jacks_colon that's because CROSS APPLY doesn't exist in SQL Server 2000, as well as VARCHAR(MAX), etc.

Comment: I'm fairly certain that 2000 does not support cross apply or TVFs. 2005 introduced user-defined functions.

Comment: And why have the company you work for not upgraded? It's been out support for years (since 2010 at least iirc). It's unlikely it'll be compatible with any modern applications and you'll also not be compliant with most security laws out there (especially the new GDPR laws in Europe). I don't think the problem here is your SQL, it's the ancient technology you're working with. Fix that and you can use T-SQL that is actually supported and documented.

Comment: I had a sneaking suspicion that the cause was because of the version of sql server I'm using, that's why I made sure to include that in my OP. Thanks to everyone that pointed that out. This will give me one more thing to point out to the powers that be here to hopefully convince them to allow an upgrade. I tried to give you all useful comment upvotes but I don't have the option, possibly because my reputation is too low :(

Comment: You're right, everyone here appears to be in agreement; the version of SQL Server you're using is very out of date and it's way past time to upgrade. You're priority right now isn't getting what you have working, it's getting the company you work for to update their tech. If they're still running SQL Server 2000, it actually concerns me what else they're running (for example, are all their users still on XP machines?).

Comment: @SMor - in agreement with most other comments here, but UDFs themselves did exists in 2000.

Comment: I just stepped into this role a couple of months ago and I seem to find atrocious things around every corner, like SQL Server 2000 being the used. I haven't found any Windows XP machines but it wouldn't surprise me at this point if I did!